# join table themselves and order by max date

Tags: sql

i have a table like in the picture :

[image]

i want list posts order by date.
if a post has no comment post date as date.
if a post has comments , last comment date as post date.

the result like the picture :

what is the sql query for this?

Comment: According to your description, it seems you need to have two date columns in the first table, as post date and comment date

Answer (score 0):

select * from YOUR_TABLE_NAME where Parentid is null order by date asc;

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
select *,(select max(date) from table as t2 where t2.parentid = t1.postid ) as maxdate 
   from table as t1 
   where type = 'P'
   order by maxdate asc
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach coalesces the maximum date from the comments, with the maximum date from the children:

```
select p.*,
       coalesce(p2.maxdate, p.date) as date
from posts p left join
     (select p2.parentid, max(p2.date) as maxdate
      from posts p2
      where p2.parentid is not null
      group by p2.parentid
     ) pc
     on pc.parentid = p.postid
where p.type = 'P'
order by coalesce(p2.maxdate, p.date) asc;
```

There is another interesting approach using aggregation, if you wanted fewer columns (it is a bit cumbersome to get all the columns).

To just get the date for each post:

```
select coalesce(parentid, postid) as postid,
       max(date)
from posts p  
group by  coalesce(parentid, postid);
```